# SampleData created in Blend not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, prototype, expression-blend

I am currently creating a proto using Expressions Blend.

I created a SampleDataSource and added Collection. This collection has 5 simple properties.

After setting that up, I dragged and dropped the SampleDataSource to the Silverlight page that i created in Blend (same project) and created the Datagrid.

The SampleData and the grid works well.

Now when I open the same page in Visual Studio 2010 I get several errors:
The most significant I find is:
Error 4 Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource' that is not included in the assembly. C:\Projects\Moneydashboard\Management client\ManagementClient\ManagementClient\SampleDataSource.xaml 6 47 ManagementClient

Basically I want to run the proto I created in Blend to run and compile in VS 2010.

Thanks and regards,
Mayur Kotlikar

Comment: Is it the same solution that you open in `VS` as the one you open in `Blend`? Looks like it's missing `Assembly Reference`. Try to look into failed references in `VS` by expanding `References` folder and looking for a `Yellow Exclamation (!)`.

Comment: I created a new project in Visual Studio, which was Silverlight Navigation type. I then added the silverlight pages that I created in Blend to this new Visual Studio project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have included all the data related files from your Blend project (xaml + cs + xsd) and added the datasource correctly in the App.xaml file.

Consider opening your VS2010 project in Blend and add the datasource directly to the project that way around. You can easily open your VS2010 project in Blend by right-clicking a XAML file and choose Edit in Blend.

Comment: When I open the solution in Visual Studio, everything works fine